# value from a JToken.ToString() always null

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, json.net

Having a string problem where the value of JToken is always coming across as null in debug, however the value displays in the watch window.

this is the conversion code

```
JToken obj = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText))["Message"];
var value = obj.ToString();
```

value is always comning across null, however if you look at the screenshot of my watch window you can see there is value.

[image: WatchWindow]

The actual data being used:

```
responseText = 
"{\"ClassName\":\"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException\",\"Message\":\"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)\",\"Data\":{\"HelpLink.ProdName\":\"Microsoft SQL Server\",\"HelpLink.EvtSrc\":\"MSSQLServer\",\"HelpLink.EvtID\":\"-1\",\"HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl\":\"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink\",\"HelpLink.LinkId\":\"20476\",\"SqlError 1\":\"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)\"},\"InnerException\":null,\"HelpURL\":null,\"StackTraceString\":\"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)\\r\\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\\r\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\\r\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\\r\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)\\r\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\\r\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\\r\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)\\r\\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)\\r\\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)\\r\\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()\\r\\n   at MieTrakDotNetCoreAPI.Utilities.DaoUtil.ExecuteStoredProcedure(String procedureName, String[] parameters) in E:\\\\Projects\\\\MieTrak2018\\\\CustomerCustomizations\\\\MieTrakDotNetCoreAPI\\\\MieTrakDotNetCoreAPI\\\\Utilities\\\\DaoUtil.cs:line 111\",\"RemoteStackTraceString\":null,\"RemoteStackIndex\":0,\"ExceptionMethod\":null,\"HResult\":-2146232060,\"Source\":\"Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider\",\"WatsonBuckets\":null,\"Errors\":null,\"ClientConnectionId\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\"}"
```

Comment: Ran your exact code and json in Linqpad and it worked just fine.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKcd4.png - how are you checking the result of value? Note if you have a breakpoint on that line that the value won't be assigned when the code breaks, you have to step over the line to assign the value..

Comment: I'm running it in a MonoAndroid app.. and value is definitely being assigned as null, I'm checking the value after.  I think it may be a problem with the framework

Comment: Can't reproduce in a .Net fiddle, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/sw0R1O.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm) to get data.

For example:

```
JToken obj = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText));
var value = obj.SelectToken("Message").ToString();
```